# Check even number in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am learning Angular right now and i have an error. I have a button and when i click this button i increase this variable by 1.

```
checkNumber=0;

increaseLength(event: any){
this.checkNumber = this.checkNumber+1;
}
```

Now i want to show if the current "checkNumber" is even or not so i created the following variable:

```
isEven = false;

increaseLength(event: any){
this.checkNumber = this.checkNumber+1;
if(this.checkNumber % 2 != 0){
  this.isEven == false;
}
else{
  this.isEven == true;
}
console.log(this.isEven);
}
```

The problem is, that this function alway returns `false` no matter what the actual number is. (I trigger the increaseLength() function with a button click).

Comment: Angular is still javascript. Just use the modulus operator like in any other language. If `this.checkNumber % 2 ==0 ` then your number is even.

Comment: `==` is a **comparison** operator. Assignment is `=`. Side note: Your entire `if`/`else` can be replaced with `this.isEven = this.checkNumber % 2 == 0;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this.isEven == false; This should be an assignment here , rather you are checking for condition in your code. It should be :

```
this.isEven = false;
```

and

```
this.isEven = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

When you want to assign value to a variable you're writing only one = and not  ==, when you want to check if it equals to something then use ==

```
isEven = false;

increaseLength(event: any){
this.checkNumber = this.checkNumber+1;
if(this.checkNumber % 2 != 0){
  this.isEven = false;
}
else{
  this.isEven = true;
}
console.log(this.isEven);
}
```

This should work but I prefer to use this function, much more shorter:

```
function isEven(n) {
   return n % 2 == 0;
}
```

If it returns true so it will be even if not it will be odd so just to add one if.

Answer (score 0):

It should be an assignment to `this.isEven`:

```
isEven = false;

increaseLength(event: any){
  this.checkNumber = this.checkNumber+1;
  if(this.checkNumber % 2 != 0){
   this.isEven = false;
  }
  else{
   this.isEven = true;
  }
  console.log(this.isEven);
}
```

Also you can massively simplify your code:

```
isEven = false;

increaseLength(event: any) {
  this.checkNumber += 1;

  this.isEven = this.checkNumber % 2 === 0;

  console.log(this.isEven);
}
```